# How to get Studio3T to show collection data automatically?

Tags: studio3t

Why I have to press F5 everytime to get data from my collections?

I imported a database in Studio3T free version, Everytime I'mtry to get data from collection I have to click on run entier script button/F5 to get data from each collection which too irritating is there anyway that i get data directly or script run automatically when i click on my collection to look at data.